# sql join not displaying correctly

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm currently trying to join two tables with a left join:

--portal--

- id_portal (index)
- id_venue
- name_portal

---

--access--

- id_access (index)
- id_event
- id_portal
- id_tickets
- scan_access

---

'access' contains a number of ticket types per portal for each event.  I need to combine these to get the sum total of the scan_access column for each portal but include the portals that have 'null' scan_access to come up with '0'.  To achieve this I've used a left join:

```sql
SELECT portal.name_portal, SUM(access.scan_access) AS total_scan 
FROM portal LEFT JOIN access ON portal.id_portal = access.id_portal 
WHERE portal.id_venue = $venueId 
GROUP BY portal.id_portal 
ORDER BY portal.id_portal ASC
```

which means I get the following:

- Portal 1 - Null
- Portal 2 - 40
- Portal 3 - 33
- Portal 4 - Null

but I have an issue when I need to also get the above result when taking into account the event (id_event) because when I use the following:

```sql
SELECT portal.name_portal, SUM(access.scan_access) AS total_scan 
FROM portal LEFT JOIN access ON portal.id_portal = access.id_portal 
WHERE portal.id_venue = $venueId AND access.id_event = 20 
GROUP BY portal.id_portal 
ORDER BY portal.id_portal ASC
```

I get:

- Portal 2 - 40
- Portal 3 - 33

which makes sense as those are the only two rows that have an id_event value.  But how can I take this col into account without losing the other portals?  also, is there a way in sql to make the 'null' a zero when returning a result?  (I can fix the null after with php but wanted to see if it was possible)

Comment: can u give example how u want the ouput wil be

Comment: I'm not sure what you edited ThinkingStiff

Comment: I made it so the SQL wasn't all on one line and added a formatting hint so it's colored.

Comment: ah, I'm not a fan of putting it on different lines normally.  is there any advantage other than reading?

Comment: For questions it's much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting `access.id_event = 20` in your `WHERE` clause, you turn your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. Move `access.id_event = 20` into your join criteria to preserve your `LEFT JOIN`. As @echo_me mentioned, you can use `COALESCE()` to get rid of your zeroes. I'd put it around the `SUM()`, instead of inside.

```sql
SELECT portal.name_portal, COALESCE( SUM(access.scan_access), 0 ) AS total_scan 
FROM portal LEFT JOIN access ON portal.id_portal = access.id_portal AND access.id_event = 20 
WHERE portal.id_venue = $venueId
GROUP BY portal.id_portal 
ORDER BY portal.id_portal ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

to convert NULL to 0 use this

```
 COALESCE(col, 0)
```

in your example it will be

```
     SUM(COALESCE(access.scan_access, 0)) AS total_scan
```